# Disable server side validation rules for hidden view controls

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-5

Which is the proper way to disable validation rule on server side for those controls that are hidden on the client side?

As far as I know, client side validation is automatically disabled for hidden form controls, but on server side ModelState.IsValid still is false (of course server doesn't know anything about what is done on client).

In my sample test (a registration form with a RegisterViewModel class) the only way I found is to add another field (PasswordHidden) in the model .
On Client side this field value is set via jQuery.
The toggleDiv button is used to hide/show some fields on the client.

This is the view :

```
@model m2m.Models.ViewModels.RegisterViewModel

@{ViewBag.Title = "Register";}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new
{
    @id = "registerFormId",
    @class = "form-horizontal",
    role = "form"
}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger  " })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pwdDiv">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger " })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })   <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger " })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="toggleDiv" value="Clicca">Click here!</button>

    @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.PasswordHidden)

}
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#toggleDiv").on("click",function () {
                
                var div = $("#pwdDiv");

                if (div.attr("hidden") == null) {
                    div.attr("hidden", true)
                    $("#PasswordHidden").val('true');
                    
                }
                else {
                    div.attr("hidden", false);
                    $("#PasswordHidden").val('false');
                   
                }
                
            });

        });
       
    </script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

In the controller I remove from ModelState if PasswordHidden is true:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel viewModel)
{
   if (viewModel.PasswordHidden.HasValue && viewModel.PasswordHidden.Value==true) 
   {
     ModelState.Remove("Password");
     ModelState.Remove("PasswordConfirm");
   }
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     //do something
   }
   else
      return View(viewModel);
}
```

The viewmodel code:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Metti la password.")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    
    public bool? PasswordHidden { get; set; }

    
}
```

This works for me in this simple scenario, but, for more complex situation, are there other ways?